# How to solve [FlowExchangeError: redirect_uri_mismatch] / [FlowExchangeError: invalid_grant] on a google app engine app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-earth-engine

I need to make an app via app engine, I am familiarizing with the [demos] (https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/tree/master/demos). I have successfully deployed all of them except for "export-to-drive". I am able to deploy it, but I get a **500 Internal Server Error**. It is the same on the cloud shell, but when I run it locally it run well.

Since the web console shows no error, I checked in the cloud shell console and got those errors:

- redirect_uri_mismatch
- invalid_grant

I tried to authorize all the redirect domains I could think of, but nothing changes. I know it is not my API key because it is working when I run the code locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up both Service account and OAuth 2.0 Client ID credentials  to [authorize requests to Earth Engine.](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_intro#2-set-up-credentials)

Make sure that client_id and redirect_uri are properly configured as instructed [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingclient)

Note that the value redirect_uri must match an authorized URI you have set up in [API console](https://console.developers.google.com/) > Credentials >
 Client ID for Web application > Authorized redirect URIs
.